# Understanding an Algorithm for Singular Value Decomposition of a square matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

First time user of the site, so I apologize if my question isn't worded properly.

I'm trying to implement the SVD of a square matrix using Algorithm 6 found on [this website](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf) in C:

Regarding the step where it says:

> Determine d1, d2, c = cos(θ), and s = sin(ϕ) such that...

In this step, what is the difference between the elements of the middle matrix? As in, isn't `u2k,i` the same as `uk,i` `uk,i`? (The top two elements in the matrix/the left two elements in the matrix)

If not, how should I be reading this algorithm?

Comment: This is a completely uneducated guess, as I know nothing about SVD algorithms, but could it be a typo and that the off-diagonal elements should be `u_k,i` `u_k,j`? I don't see why they would write out `u` twice unless the subscripts were meant to be different. The equations also look like what you would find in a correlation matrix from probability if you write them this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to read information on basic numerical or mathematical techniques, it is usually a good idea to have a working understanding of common mathematical notations.

Where you have used u2k,i, the description in "Algorithm" has the 2 as a superscript, and "k,i" as a subscript.

Basic mathematics:  2 as a superscript usually means "to the power of 2".  And that is the case in the document you linked to.

In TeX, the term would have been written as $u_{k,i}^2$.  The _ means subscript, ^ means superscript.

You might also want to note that your question has exactly nothing to do with the C programming language, so I would be unsurprised if a moderator suggests moving it elsewhere.